# bad numeric config value when using git clone

Tags: git, macos

Whenever I use `git clone`, I get this message. What shall I do?

```
fatal: bad numeric config value '5242880000' for 'http.postbuffer': out of range
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Look in `git config --edit --global` and `--system` to find that value, then remove a few zeros.

Comment: Thanks. But what to look? These commands only produce traditional help messages, like 'use global config/system file'.

Comment: I remove one zero and it works. Thank you. Btw, why I would get extra zeros in the first place?

Comment: looks like Linus Torvalds still got some homework to do