# bad numeric config value 'client_max_body_size' for 'http.hostBuffer:' invalid unit

Tags: git, android-studio, git-clone

Before this issue Git is working perfectly with **Command line** and **Android Studio**. But after run this `git config --global http.postBuffer client_max_body_size` command its stopped working and send me below error. For this command I have followed this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6842687/the-remote-end-hung-up-unexpectedly-while-git-cloning/6849424#6849424) of SO.

```
bad numeric config value 'client_max_body_size' for 'http.hostBuffer:' invalid unit
```

I have checked [Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34995823/nginx-invalid-number-of-arguments-in-client-max-body-size), [Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43272369/client-max-body-size-for-images-in-location), [Question 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21328687/git-init-bad-numeric-config-value-auto-for-core-autocrlf-in/21328799#comment88864503_21328799) and some other questions. I have tried to uninstall Git setup and reinstall again also but then also its not working. My system is Window 10.

When I try to clone the project it is show me as below.
[image]

I have checked questions'answer and tried to fixed but not getting solution. Let me know where and how I can fix this.

Comment: Where do you see `client_max_body_size` in the linked answer? The linked answer shows how to write the command correctly.

Comment: @phd I see that kind of option in bitbucket forms. But there only description not specified that how to write that command. Its happen because I have used string value instead of numeric value. I got the solution by `edit` command. For check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/34516755/5815673